# internal Neumann boundary for FEM

Tags: finite-element-method

Following the documentation for `NeumannValue` (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html) gives the impression, that it is only possible to set Neumann boundaries outside of a mesh, not inside.

Ignoring that description and setting up internal Neumann boundaries seems to work, though:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

(** create mesh **)
mesh = ToElementMesh[ToBoundaryMesh[
    "Coordinates" -> {{0}, {1}, {2}},
    "BoundaryElements" -> {PointElement[{{1}, {2}, {3}}, {1, 2, 3}]}
    ]];

(** solve PDE **)
diffcoeff = 1;
sol = NDSolveValue[{
    Div[diffcoeff Grad[u[x], {x}], {x}] + 1 == 
     NeumannValue[10, x == 1],
    DirichletCondition[u[x] == 1, x == 0],
    DirichletCondition[u[x] == -1, x == 2]
    },
   u, x \[Element] mesh];

(** plot solution **)
plotOptions = {PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}
   , PlotRangePadding -> {None, Automatic}};
p1 = Show[
   Plot[sol[x], {x, 0, 2}],
   Evaluate[plotOptions], FrameLabel -> {"x", "u"}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["function", Black, 20]
   ];
p2 = Show[
   Plot[sol'[x], {x, 0, 2}]
   , Evaluate[plotOptions], FrameLabel -> {"x", "u'"}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["1st derivative", Black, 20], 
   Prolog -> {Gray, Dashed, Line[{{0, #}, {2, #}}] & /@ {-6, 4}}
   ];
p3 = Show[
   Plot[sol''[x] + 1, {x, 0, 2}]
   , Evaluate[plotOptions], FrameLabel -> {"x", "u''-(-1)"}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["2nd derivative error", Black, 20]
   ];
plot = Grid[{{p1, p2, p3}}]
```

[image]

Interestingly, the first derivative of the solution is not equal to 10 at the internal boundary, but instead the derivative jumps by 10 at the internal boundary. 
The condition imposed on the second derivative (= -1) is fulfilled on the entire mesh.

What surprised me at first is that the second order PDE should only require 2 boundary conditions to solve it uniquely and I was naively expecting NDSolve not to work. However, that is only true for a continuous first derivative, which is obviously violated for the jump enforced by the internal Neumann boundary.

Mathematically it works out:

$u''=-1$

$u'=-x+C_1$

$u=-x^2/2+C_1x+C_2$

Now we assume a different set of coefficients $\{C_1,C_2\}$ and $\{\tilde{C}_1,\tilde{C}_{2}\}$ in the two domains divided by the Neumann boundary condition. In total these are four, so we need four conditions to identify them. These are:

$u(0)=1$

$\tilde{u}(2)=-1$

$u'(1)=\tilde{u}'(1)-10$

$u(1)=\tilde{u}(1)$

So a unique solution should exist :)

(Actually, solving for the coefficients gives the same answer as Mathematica.)

---

My questions are:

1) Is that interpretation correct? Since the documentation does not address this, I would appreciate some feedback.

2) Is there a way to enforce a first derivative value at an inside boundary? Looking at the math part above it seems this would lead to 5 conditions instead of 4. So the system is overdetermined unless one gets rid of one of the Dirichlet conditions or the continuity in $u$.

Comment: I think the key problem is that Neumann Conditions operate on the normal of an element.  At an internal point, there are two normals because there is an element on either side of the point leading to an ambiguity in the specification.  I have modeled jump conditions in concentrations as found in gas absorption by modeling a thin interface region as shown at the [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1551098).

Comment: I don't think that I understand your point. If I look at an FEM mesh, I can also define normals for all the elements without contact to the boundary. For a mesh consisting of triangles. Each triangle has 3 normals. Also: I have read your Wolfram Community post before. I liked it a lot.

Comment: Thanks.  The connectivity of elements need to have consistent ordering like a right hand rule.  If you have a mesh consisting of only two triangles that share an edge (e.g., `ToElementMesh[
 "Coordinates" -> {{0., 0.}, {1., 0.}, {1., 1.}, {0., 1.}}, 
 "MeshElements" -> {TriangleElement[{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 1}}]}]` will work but reversing the triangle ordering of an element will cause it to fail), what is the normal of the shared edge? The normal of triangle 1 points into triangle 2 and vice versa. There two normals pointing in opposite directions.